# Creating JTextArea

Tags: java, netbeans-7

i'm using some code to getfilenames and store it on a DB and everything works fine, but i wanted to show what files it stored on a TextArea, how can i do it?

Here is the code used to store the file names. BTW i'm doing this in NetBeans.

```
private void ActualizerBDActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        Conectar();
        File folder = null;
    try {
        String ppp = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();            
        folder = new File(ppp + "\\ImagensDB");
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
    }
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        String query = "insert into dados (Num, Nome, Autor, Data, Preco, Categoria)" +"values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement prepStmt=null;
    try {
        prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JanelaPrincipal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        for (int j = 0; j < listOfFiles.length; j++) {
                 if (listOfFiles[j].isFile()) {
            try {
                String text = listOfFiles[j].getName();
                String txsp[] = text.split("-");
                      prepStmt.setString(1, txsp[0]);
                      prepStmt.setString(2, txsp[1]);
                      prepStmt.setString(3, txsp[2]);
                      prepStmt.setString(4, txsp[3]);
                      prepStmt.setString(5, txsp[4]);
                      prepStmt.setString(6, txsp[5]);
                      prepStmt.execute(); // executa o INSERT
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JanelaPrincipal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
      }
}
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados Introduzidos com Sucesso!");
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JanelaPrincipal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using a `JList` instead of the `JTextArea`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere here you could

```
String text = listOfFiles[j].getName();
String txsp[] = text.split("-");
prepStmt.setString(1, txsp[0]);
prepStmt.setString(2, txsp[1]);
prepStmt.setString(3, txsp[2]);
prepStmt.setString(4, txsp[3]);
prepStmt.setString(5, txsp[4]);
prepStmt.setString(6, txsp[5]);
prepStmt.execute(); // executa o INSERT

myTextArea.append(text + "\n");
```

Of course you need to have build the ui first! Check out [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more elp

Comment: I'm a little noob so sorry for the silly questions, but i created a jTextArea in Other Components on the GUI from netbeans, but even if i append the text to it it still doesn't show.

Comment: Obviously, make sure your referencing the correct `JTextArea` (you have no idea how many times this comes out as an issue).  Make sure your only updating the `JTextArea` in the **Event Dispatching Thread** (`ETD`) and you may need to call `invalidate()` and/or `repaint()` on the component.  Also, don't perform any time consuming processes on the `ETD`

Comment: thanks for your help i guess i'm still not experienced enough, even refering to the correct component it still doens't show but i really apprecite your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

- read file names from database:

> "Select fileName from YourTable"

- add the names to textarea in for-each

> textArea.append(fileName + "\n");

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
textarea.append(text + " stored successfully\n");
```

immediately after your execute statement.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Create a JTextArea like this...

```
   JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
```

**2. Read the file** which contains the data from the Data Base.

**3.** And then **write it to the JTextArea**

```
   File f = new File("d:\\My.txt");
   FileReader fr = new  FileReader(f);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);


   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   String s = null;

   while ((br.readLine())!=null){

       sb.append(br.readLine());

     }

  s = sb.toString();

 txt.setText(s);
```